# Consistency of Dirichlet Distribution

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let  $Y_{i}=(X_{1i}, X_{2i},..., X_{Ki})\sim \operatorname{Multinomial}(N,(p_{1}, p_{2},..., p_{K})) \ \ i=1, 2,..., n$ iid random draws from a $\operatorname{Multinomial}$ distribution, i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^{K}X_{ki}=N$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{K}p_{k}=1$.

If we want to make $\textit{Bayesian Inference},$ a convenient prior choice for the probabilities $p_{k} \ \ i=k, 2,..., K$,  that we want to infer, is a $\textit{Dirichlet}$ distribution.

$p=(p_{1}, p_{2},..., p_{K})\sim \operatorname{Dirichlet}(a_{1}, a_{2},..., a_{K})$

The $\textit{Dirichlet}$ prior is conjugate to the $\textit{Multinomial}$ likelihood, hence the posterior distribution will be again a $\textit{Dirichlet}$.

$p=(p_{1}, p_{2},..., p_{K})|(Y_{1}, Y_{2},..., Y_{n})\sim \operatorname{Dirichlet}(a_{1} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{1i}, a_{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{2i},..., a_{k}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{Ki})$

---

A definition of posterior consistency that I found in this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320104/proof-of-posterior-consistency says

“given the data $x_1,...,x_n$ iid and the model $f(x;\theta)$, if we have posterior consistency at $\theta_0$, then
$\forall \epsilon > 0$,
$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\pi(|\theta-\theta_0|>\epsilon|X)=0$.”

---

My goal is to prove that this type of consistency holds for the bayesian model described earlier, i.e. I assume I have to prove consistency at $p^{0} = (p^{0}_{1}, p^{0}_{2},..., p^{0}_{K})$.

For that I have to calculate the
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\pi(\left \| p-p^{0} \right \|\geq \epsilon|Y_{1}, Y_{2},..., Y_{n}) =0 $$

---

I have to start by specifying a norm, suppose that I use the $\textit{Euclidean}$ norm (we could also use the $L_{1}$ norm), i.e. $\left \| p-p_{0} \right \| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{K}(p_{k}-p_{k}^{0})^{2}}$

$$\pi(\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{K}(p_{k}-p_{k}^{0})^{2}}\geq \epsilon\mid Y_{1}, Y_{2},..., Y_{n})$$

How do I move forward with proving that?

---

$\textbf{Update}$, I tried to examine what happens when $K=2$

$$\pi(\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{2}(p_{k}-p_{k}^{0})^{2}}\geq \epsilon\mid Y_{1}, Y_{2},..., Y_{n}) = \pi(\sqrt{(p_{1}-p_{1}^{0})^{2}+(p_{2}-p_{2}^{0})^{2}} \geq \epsilon |Y_{1}, Y_{2},..., Y_{n})$$

$$=\pi(\sqrt{(p_{1}-p_{1}^{0})^{2}+(1-p_{1}-1+p_{1}^{0})^{2}} \geq \epsilon |Y_{1}, Y_{2},..., Y_{n}) = \pi(\sqrt{2(p_{1}-p_{1}^{0})^{2}} \geq \epsilon |Y_{1}, Y_{2},..., Y_{n}) =  \pi(\sqrt{2}\left | p_{1}-p_{1}^{0} \right | \geq \epsilon |Y_{1}, Y_{2},..., Y_{n})$$

Then the posterior mean and variance of $p_{1}$ are

$$M = \mathbb{E}[p_{1}|Y_{1}, Y_{2},..., Y_{n}] = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{2}a_{k}}{\sum_{k=1}^{2}a_{k}+nN}(\frac{a_{1}}{\sum_{k=1}^{2}a_{k}}) + \frac{nN}{\sum_{k=1}^{2}+nN}(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{1i}}{nN})$$

$$V = \frac{(a_{1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{1i})(a_{1}+a_{2}+nN-a_{1}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{1i})}{(a_{1}+a_{2}+nN)^{2}(a_{1}+a_{2}+nN+1)}\rightarrow 0$$
as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Similarly with the argument used in this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320104/proof-of-posterior-consistency, we have

$$\pi(\left | p_{1}-p_{1}^{0} \right | \geq \epsilon/\sqrt{2} |Y_{1}, Y_{2},..., Y_{n}) \leq \pi(\left | p_{1}-M \right | \geq (\epsilon/2\sqrt{2}) |Y_{1}, Y_{2},..., Y_{n}) + \pi(\left | M-p_{1}^{0} \right | \geq (\epsilon/2\sqrt{2}) |Y_{1}, Y_{2},..., Y_{n})$$

Where in the RHS, the first term goes to zero due to Markov Inequality, and the second term goes also to zero because $M$ is a consistent estimator of $p_{1}$.

However, how can we extend this to $K>2$??

---

$\textbf{Thought},$ Since, the $\textit{Dirichlet}$ distribution is a generalization of the $\textit{Beta}$ distribution, and the mean of each componenet $p_{k}$ of the $\textit{Dirichlet}$ is the same with the mean of the marginized distribution of $p_{k}$ which is a $\textit{Beta}$ distribution.

Then would it be sufficient to check consistency for each $p_{k}$ based on the consistency of their marginalized $\textit{Beta}$ distribution, i.e. to check

$$\pi_{Beta}(\left | p_{k}-p_{k}^{0} \right | \geq \epsilon |Y_{1}, Y_{2},..., Y_{n})$$

where $\pi_{Beta}$ is the marginal of the $\textit{Dirichlet}$ posterior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This holds true for every prior $\pi$, not just a Dirichlet prior. Partition the simplex into sets of diameter $\epsilon/3$. The true parameter $\theta=\theta_0$ is in one of them, call it $Q$, where $\pi(Q)>0$. Let $Q_a$ consist of all points within distance at most $a\epsilon/3$ from $Q$. Then the posterior probability of $Q_{2}^c$ tends to zero a.s on the event that the true parameter is in $Q$.

Proof:
(Edit: Adding some detail to the previous sketch.)
Write $P(\cdot)=\int P_\theta(\cdot) \,d\pi(\theta)$, with $E$ the corresponding expectation operator.
Define
$$A_n=\{Y_n/n \in Q_1 \}\,$$
and let
$$f_n(Y)=P(\theta \in Q_2^c |Y_1,...,Y_n)$$
be the posterior probability of $Q_2^c$ given the first $n$ samples. Then
$$E[f_n(Y) 1_{A_n}]=P[\{\theta \in Q_2^c\} \cap A_n]= 
 \int_{Q_2^c} P_\theta(A_n ) \, d\pi(\theta)$$
tends to zero exponentially fast by Hoeffding. Thus
$$ E[\sum_n f_n(Y) 1_{A_n}] <\infty \,,$$
whence $f_n(Y)1_{A_n} \to 0$ almost surely with respect to $P$.
But we also have $1_{A_n^c} \to 0$ a.s. with respect to $P( \cdot| \theta \in Q)$ by the strong law of large numbers. We conclude that
$$P(f_n(Y) \to 0 | \theta \in Q) =1 \,.$$

Comment: Yuval thank you very much for the answer. I just wanted to ask how do we get from the joint probability, to the integral and how the Hoeffdings inequality gets into the proof?? I understand that the joint probability wants to check what happens when the estimated proportion due to LLN go to the correct area and we assume that $\theta$ is outside of the correct area

Comment: I think I got how the Hoeffdings inequality is used, it is used for the probability inside the integral. However, how we go from the joint to the integrated probability I'm still confused

Comment: @Jonathan1234   I added details to the previous sketch. Let me know if some step is still unclear.